# How to select array in ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array like this and I will save it into a variable with the name list

```
[
  {
    "current_customer_count"=>0,
    "email"=>"test1@mail.com",
    "is_available"=>true,
    "user_roles"=>[{"id"=>001, "name"=>"NAME 1"}]
  },
  {
    "current_customer_count"=>0,
    "email"=>"test2@mail.com",
    "is_available"=>true,
    "user_roles"=>[{"id"=>002, "name"=>"NAME 2"}]
  },
  {
    "current_customer_count"=>1,
    "email"=>"test3@mail.com",
    "is_available"=>true,
    "user_roles"=>[{"id"=>003, "name"=>"NAME 1"}]
  },
]
```

From the data variable that contains the array value, I want to select based on the key "name" equal to "NAME 1" and will be saved into a new variable.
This is the way I do it:

```
new_variable = list.select do |key|
  key[:user_roles].select do |data|
    data[:name] == "NAME 1"
  end
end
```

But this way I did not work. I get all the same array values ​​as before.
How can I get an array value by selecting based on key "name" equal to "NAME 1"?

> Note, this is the result I was supposed to get

```
[
  {
    "current_customer_count"=>0,
    "email"=>"test1@mail.com",
    "is_available"=>true,
    "user_roles"=>[{"id"=>001, "name"=>"NAME 1"}]
  },
  {
    "current_customer_count"=>1,
    "email"=>"test3@mail.com",
    "is_available"=>true,
    "user_roles"=>[{"id"=>003, "name"=>"NAME 1"}]
  },
]
```

I am very grateful for your answer

Comment: The return value of `key[:user_roles].select` is an array. An array is not `false`, it is an array. Therefore, the block passed to `list.select` will be trueish for every `key` and thus select all keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is

```rb
list.select { |customer| customer['user_roles'].any? { |role| role["name"] == 'NAME 1' }  }
```